# Subtract one day from time method in php

Tags: php

I have the following query in some code...

```
$student_result = db_query("select id,timestamp,time_id,unschedule_code from student where canceled='0' and email='".$email."' and timestamp > '".time()."'");
```

I want to change and timestamp > '".time()."'"); to time - 1 day. I tryed something like...

```
$student_result = db_query("select id,timestamp,time_id,unschedule_code from student where canceled='0' and email='".$email."' and timestamp > '".time(). - 1"'");
```

...with no luck. Page simply fails to load, so I'm sure the syntax is not even valid. Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamps are in seconds, try:

```
$student_result = db_query("select id,timestamp,time_id,unschedule_code from student where canceled='0' and email='".$email."' and timestamp > '".(time()-(3600*24))."'");
```

Comment: Boom! You nailed it bro. Good call.